# How to get valid url for Web API method with RoutePrefix in the javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, typescript

WebApiConfig

```vb
'...
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name:="DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
)
'...
```

Global.asax

```vb
Protected Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf WebApiConfig.Register)
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
End Sub
```

Web API controller

```vb
<Authorize()>
<RoutePrefix("api/customer")>
Public Class CustomerController
   Inherits ApiController

    <Route("saveName")>
    <HttpPost>
    Public Function saveName(value As MyTypeOfValues) As IHttpActionResult
        'Do some staff
    End Function

End Class
```

Request method:

```
  var actionurl = "api/customer/saveName";
  $.ajax(actionurl,
  {
     dataType: "JSON",
     data: customerdata,
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     error: function() { alert('error');}
  }).done(function (result) { alert(result);});
```

with url = `api/customer/saveName`
request was sended to `http://localhost/MySiteName/Customer/ShowCustomer/api/customer/saveName`
and get Error 404

with url = `/api/customer/saveName`
request was sended to `http://localhost/api/customer/saveName`
and get Error 404

with url = `http://localhost/MySiteName/api/customer/saveName`
which I manually create and send by Fiddler - work fine.

In the different answers of the related questions suggested urls didn't work in my case

Question: How I can generate valid url for Web API request in the javascript/typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by using .NET code in the Razor view (MyView.vbhtml)

```
var baseUrl: string = "@Url.Content("~/")";
```

This variable passed to the constructor of the viewmodel(typescript)
and Web API url can be generated using that value

```
var actionUrl: string = this._baseurl + "api/customer/saveName";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want  `http://localhost/MySiteName/api/customer/saveName` you need everthing after the host name ... starting with the trailing slash:

`url = /MySiteName/api/customer/saveName`

Note: I highly recommend looking into *generating* typescript code to call these instead of hand typing these *on the server* and duplicating *on the client*. Just a point of failure you really can do without.

Comment: problem is that `MySiteName` is name of my developing site name. It will change in the production site.

Comment: Then you can try and parse it out of `window.location` (split on `/` and take `1`)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Url.Content("~/")` to store exactly the baseUrl in the main page, `_LayoutMain` for example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resolveClientUrl(relativeUrl) {
        return '@Url.Content("~/")' + relativeUrl;
    }
</script>
```

After that, you can resolve the `relativeUrl` like below:

```
var url = resolveClientUrl("api/customer/saveName");
```